# Accessing start up bits of SRAM from MicroBit for PUF

Tags: arduino-ide, memory

https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF51822_PS_v3.4.pdf

The aim is to extract (output in serial monitor) the start up bits from  the SRAM of this microbit which is located at memory address 0x20000000, given by the datasheet above, all done in the arduino IDE.

After some searches I emerged on this code

```
void setup() 
{
  uint8_t const * p;
  uint8_t i;

  Serial.begin( 115200 );
  
  p = 0;
  i = 0;
  
  do
  {
    Serial.print( *p, HEX );
    Serial.print( ' ' );
    
    ++i;
    ++p;
    
    if ( (i & 0xF) == 0 )
    {
      Serial.println();
    }
  }
  while ( i != 0 );
}

void loop() 
{
}
```

From this link https://forum.arduino.cc/t/accessing-sram-on-arduino-uno/267777/6

However this pertains to an arduino uno and I'm not entirely sure how I would transfer it to my microbit.